# Do we use a singular or plural noun when referring to a common thing that many things have?

Tags: grammatical-number

For example, in this sentence:

> Remind employees to write their name/names on the schedule/schedules on the lid/lids of the photocopiers.

How do you think it should be written?

Personally, I think the following is best:

> Remind employees to write their names on the schedules on the lids of the photocopiers.

Comment: My first reaction to this question is: are the employees being reminded one at a time, or all at once?

Answer (score 0):

I would write

**1.** each employee has access to ALL copiers and needs to put his/her name on the single schedule which is on the lid of each copier

> Remind each employee to write their name on the schedule on the lids of the photocopiers.

**2.** each employee has access ONE copier and needs to put his/her name on the single schedule which is on the lid of that copier

> Remind each employee to write their name on the schedule on the lid of the photocopier.

or

> Remind each employee to write their name on the schedule on the lid of the photocopier they use.

Answer (score 0):

I would put everything in singular: every employee has only one name, every photocopier one lid.

Comment: But more than one photocopier

Answer (score 0):

Who is your audience and what is the context?

It would depend on where this notice or message is placed or received.  If you can put one such notice/manual/flyer on each copy room or copier, the singular might suffice.

> Remind each employee to write their name on the schedule on the lid of
>   the photocopier.

It would also depend on who the audience is. If it's an email/mass notice, and you're addressing multiple shift managers or other such responsible persons, then I would word it such that plurals could be formed as needed.  E.g.:

> Remind each employee to write his or her own name on the particular
>   schedule on the lids of each of the appropriate photocopiers.

Again, lacking context it's difficult to determine exactly what this sentence is attempting to instruct.